# Subroutine not called from worksheet_change event

Tags: excel, vba, events, excel-2010

By changing a value in a cell a call to a macro/module ) is made. When running this macro from the ribbon or  Alt + F8  it works perfectly.

Why does the call from the first macro not work?

The Macro behind Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Range("E25") Then
        Call GasFlow
    End If
End Sub
```

Macro in module 'Converse'

```
Sub GasFlow()


    ' GasFlow Macro
    ' This macro converts all gas units to Nm3/h

    '

            If Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "Nm3/h" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate")

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "Nm3/d" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") / 24

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "kg/h" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") / Range("GasMolWeight") / Range("MoleInNm3")

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "kg/d" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") / Range("GasMolWeight") / Range("MoleInNm3") / 24

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "kmol/h" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") / Range("MoleInNm3") / 1000

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "kmol/d" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") / Range("MoleInNm3") / 1000 * 24

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "SCFD" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") * 0.02831685 / 24

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "MMSCFD" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") * 28316.85 / 24

            ElseIf Range("InputGasFlowUnit") = "TPA" Then
                Range("GasFlowH") = Range("FeedGasFlowRate") / 1000 / 365 / Range("MoleInNm3") / Range("GasMolWeight")
            Else
                'No correct unit selected'

            End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question? Please explain what does not work.

Comment: The title is the question, I'll make the question more clear. Running the macro from the ribbon works. But when calling the macro from another macro does not.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is now more clear. Posted an answer, that should fix your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the worksheet code to this :

### Simpler alternative (Edit 1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$25" Then
        Call GasFlow
    End If
End Sub
```

### Better alternative

Works even when multiple cells are changed at once, including the "E25":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E25")) Is Nothing Then
        Call GasFlow
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked through a lot of MSDN websites, but I can't clearly find a good explaination about the syntax and how it is used. Searching for the keyword _Target_ and how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the first of those code options is not correct. It will trigger if the **value** of the changed cell happens to be the same as the value in E25, rather than only if it is actually E25 that is changed.